# Indivo Server Java API for authentication

Tags: java, python, xml

I am newbie in Indivo server and having an user authentication in Python for Indivo server 
using 
[Indivo app using Python](http://wiki.chip.org/indivo/index.php/HOWTO%3a_write_an_Indivo_app_using_Python)

but failed to get user authentication in JAVA.I found 
[JAva Client Authenticate](http://wiki.indivohealth.org/index.php/Java_Client_Authenticate)

So, required thing is I need JAVA API for indivo server user authentication.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the latest version of the Indivo Java client at https://github.com/downloads/chb/indivo_client_java/indivo_client_java-0.1.5.tar.gz. This will be updated soon for the latest release of Indivo Server, but in the meantime, it should be enough to authenticate to Indivo and begin making API calls.

The README file in that tarball should get you started, and there are other examples bundled with the code.

The documentation you found for JAVA client authentication is for Indivo 3.1, which has been totally rewritten in Indivo X, so don't use that page.